# Strange behaviour in IE7

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

Background

I have a page coded in .Net 1.1 and it has two dropdown lists A & B. Any changes to dropdown A will change the number of items in dropdown B which has some sample Javascript behind it. 
The only complicated bit is that it has a 5.2 MB lookup file (the file contains Javascript but located in a aspx file) which is located in a aspx file.

Where the fun begins

This has been running perfectly find in IE6 and management wants to upgrade all the browser to IE 7. This very page works in some IE 7 like my office, but it doesn't work in my client's office. The location of the web server is at a 3rd party location, so my office location has nothing to do why it works.

What I have noticed

I can download and open that massive 5.2 MB lookup file fine in my office. When I try to download that file in my client's office by right clicking download, it works fine too. However, when I tried to open that file in IE7, it always throws a syntax error on the same line which I can't see anything wrong with that line.

I hope someone can give me some ideas!! Also, firefox is not an option, so don't ask me to open it in firefox.

Comment: can you post the error message and the line that is "causing" the error?

Comment: There is nothing about that error message. It's just "syntax error". That syntax error has been fixed with change <script type="Javascript">. However, the actual page still doesn't work and I noticed that 5MB file doesn't get downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 does have a new JavaScript engine [(JScript 5.7)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Versions) - but I'm not aware of any [breaking changes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=40&p=1&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=47809025-d896-482e-a0d6-524e7e844d81&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f4%2f4%2fd%2f44de8a9e-630d-4c10-9f17-b9b34d3f6417%2fWindows+Script+Release+Notes.rtf). [IE 8 has JSCript 5.8](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2009/04/17/versioning-language-features-in-jscript.aspx) which supports versioning based on IE 8's compatiblity mode.

I would probably just attack it as a JavaScript errpr - not an IE difference. What's the line of code throwing an error?

Comment: the line of the code are just Javascript array

Make[1635] = new Array(3);
Make[1635][0] = "1";
Make[1635][1] = "A";
Make[1635][2] = "0";
Make[1636] = new Array(3);
Make[1636][0] = "2";
Make[1636][1] = "B";
Make[1636][2] = "0";
Make[1637] = new Array(3);
Make[1637][0] = "3";
Make[1637][1] = "C";
Make[1637][2] = "0";

Nevertheless, I think I may have found something about this problem. I noticed the <script> up the top of the page is <script>. I saved the file as html and changed <script type="Javascript">, it seems working now, but I need to test this with the actual web page.